# MySQL: Enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE reset

Tags: mysql, global-variables, load-data-infile

After reading several answers on here, I finally figured out why my .csv file wasn't loading in through the command prompt. I had to enable load data local infile. Once I did that, I read the global variables and they were on. I was able to load the data then. However, after closing the command prompt, I reopened it and while the variable was still reading as ON, it wouldn't allow me to import another .csv file. Do i need to turn local infile off and back on for it to work again

EDIT: this is the code that I am attempting to use to upload. It worked the first time (not even 30 minutes ago), but now it won't work

```
load data local infile '…\\Mod 8\\Vehicles_2016.csv'
into table vehicles_2016
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines
(@col1, @dummy, @dummy, @col2
,@dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy
,@dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy
,@dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy
,@dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy
)
set accident_index=@col1,vehicle_type=@col2;
```

Additionally, I tried turning off the global variable and turning it back on before loading, but that didn't work.

Comment: Please include text in your question rather than offsite images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each mysql client connection needs to be started with '--local-infile' or the corresponding option in the database API.

Comment: So you mean that when I log in, rather than JUST the mysql -u username -p password, I need to add in --local-infile? So mysql -u username -p --local-infile password?

Comment: well `mysql -u username -ppassword --local-infile` because `-p` relates to the password.