# How can I load local data in MySQL Workbench 8.0?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, load-data-infile

I am trying to load data localy from pc to MySQL database ('texnologialogismikou') but I get a lot of errors. I searched a lot in forums and in MySQL site but I couldn't find a solution.
I tried to change variables, move the file in the Workbench directory and some other things but nothing worked.

```
load data local infile 'C:\Users\Mattheos\Desktop\ActualTotalLoad-10days.csv'
Into table texnologialogismikou.actualtotalload
fields terminated by ';' enclosed by '\"' lines terminated by '\n'
```

Some of the errors I got:

> Error Code: 2. File 'C:ProgramDataMySQLMySQL Server 8.0Uploads' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
>
> Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
>
> Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

P.S. I know that there are posts like this but this is the last thing I could do. I tried everything I could find and nothing worked.

Comment: first check if the folder mentioned exists and then you have two choices, copy your data in that filder or changeing the folder, but i had here a case where this also didn't work

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60717467/6064933.

Answer (score 2):

On mySQL worckbench at the Manage Server Connections window  -> Select your connection -> Go to the Advance tab and insert OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1 in the others textinput.

Answer (score 0):

The last error message is the relevant one:

> Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

The `--secure-file-priv` option restricts from which directory files can be loaded, as [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv):

> If set to the name of a directory, the server limits import and export operations to work only with files in that directory.

You can display the configured directory with:

```
show variables like "secure_file_priv";
```

Just move the file to import to that directory, and run the `load` statement again.

Answer (score 0):

try mysqlimport

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html

or Try community edition of tools like Pentaho ETL which will load data really fast.