# How to enable LOCAL capability in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, database, csv, import, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to use LOAD DATA with the below command to import CSV files into MySQL Workbench because the wizard is incredibly slow.

```
LOAD DATA
    LOCAL INFILE 'C:\...Path...\May22 P2B.csv'
    INTO TABLE May22B.tbl_packages2buy
```

Running the above gets me 'error 3948 loading local data is disabled'. So how can I enable loading local data you ask? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993844/error-loading-local-data-is-disabled-this-must-be-enabled-on-both-the-client) with a possible solution. But I've tried running `SET GLOBAL local_infile=1` and I just get error code 1227. access denied you need (at least one of) the super privilege(s) for this operation.

So how can I get loading local data enabled, so I can use LOAD DATA and load my CSV into Workbench? or is there another fast way to load a CSV into Workbench?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: After client login to your MySQL, what is result of SELECT @@version; ?  Are you using cpanel or just workbench?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this solution?

https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,674208,674208