# Loading .csv file into MySQL database issue

Tags: mysql, database, csv

When trying to import a .csv file to my database I'm receiving the below error message:

> ERROR 3948 (42000): Loading local data is disabled; this must be
>   enabled on both the client and server sides

The attempted fix

> mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile'; mysql> SET GLOBAL
>   local_infile = 1; mysql> SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;

Confirmed that the value stated "On".  However I got the same message when I attempted to reload the .csv file.

I am rather new to MySQL.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993844/error-loading-local-data-is-disabled-this-must-be-enabled-on-both-the-client

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Issue is solved.