# Mysql Infile - works from client machine but not in server

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

MYSQL infile settings are updated to 'ON' state in config file, and verified via the show variable command.

```
show global variables like 'local_infile';

Variable_name|Value|
-------------|-----|
local_infile |ON   |
```

I am **able to load data from client machine** using the below sql code.

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE 'D:/test.csv'
INTO TABLE testtable
```

But when I try to run the same code **in my MYSQL server/machine it throws the error** as  below:

```
SQL Error [3948] [42000]: Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides
```

How can I load files from client as well as within server too ? Is it a config issue or does user need some extra rights.

Comment: Change your server config - `local-infile=1`

Comment: @symcbean - config file is already with local-infile=1 in client section and mysqld section.  Same is also visible in show variable command for local_infile as 'ON'

Comment: This might help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993844/error-loading-local-data-is-disabled-this-must-be-enabled-on-both-the-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993844/error-loading-local-data-is-disabled-this-must-be-enabled-on-both-the-client)

Comment: @RobMoll - Thank you, But I am able to load the as root user, but the non-root user is only able to load from client and not from server. Most of the actions given in the suggested link are reviewed/tried.

Comment: If you haven't already, I would run `SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;` on the "MYSQL server/machine" (from the MySQL command line of course).

Comment: focus on the client side `mysql --local_infile=1` there local_infile needs to be enabled as part of the client connection.

Comment: @danblack - client side uses connection DBEAVER IDE and same ide and config is used in server side as well.  But it works on client but not on server.  Again, I use root login it works. :(