# Dumping R data into MySQL

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

```
''' dbWriteTable(mydb, "Albums1", tracks_list) '''
```

Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :
could not run statement: Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides

This is the error I get when I try to make a table in the database, It makes the table but does not transfer the data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993844/error-loading-local-data-is-disabled-this-must-be-enabled-on-both-the-client

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: are you sure, that your data base user is allowed to write data to the DB? (the link I posted talks about the main issues related to your problem)

Comment: How would I be able to check that?

Comment: did you set up the data base or did someone give you the access data you are using in R to dump the data?

Comment: I set up the database myself

Comment: ok - then you should try to create a new user for the DB with full rights including writing to the DB (read into the mysql doc)  and use this for the conection from R ... I do not know your setup and can not replecate it but the solution should be within the link (or further links from there)

Comment: Do you have discord by any chance and could help me with this?

Comment: unfortunately I wont be of much help configuring DB and user - I know how to do the basics in postgres... you will have to wait on someone else or just dig arround the web: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql