# Mysql can not load local files

Tags: mysql

Error Code: 3948. Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides

```
show variables like 'event_scheduler'; // this is ON.
```

I saw a answer is set

```
OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1;
```

but I did not find where can set it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: Loading local data is disabled - this must be enabled on both the client and server sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993844/error-loading-local-data-is-disabled-this-must-be-enabled-on-both-the-client)

Comment: Dose your MySQL server and client run on the same computer?

Answer (score 0):

The file must be at the directory on the server. If you're using MySQL on Windows and the client is running in the same computer, it is no difference, but if your server is on the remote computer, you need the way to put the file in the server, not on the client directory.