# How to avoid this error message using R with MySql

Tags: mysql, r

I want to upload a dataframe 'mtcars' to mysql database.

This is what Ive done so far:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)
library(odbc)
library(DBI)

ydb <- DBI::dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 user='user',
                 password='password',
                 dbname='sakila',
                 host="127.0.0.1")

payment2 <- dplyr::tbl(mydb,"payment") %>% collect() # it is just a connection

copy_to(dest = mydb,df = payment2, temporary = FALSE)
```

The dataset is uploaded but it is empty, and I have this errors message:

```
*Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides*
```

Comment: Most likely a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59993844/3358272, though I don't have mysql around to verify.

Comment: Thanks for your time @r2evans. Its still not working. I did everything that post says