# setting LOCAL_INFILE in config file MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, database

I'm going through the MySQL documentation [tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/loading-tables.html). It's really great so far, but I've run into a problem. The step where the tut explains how to load initial table data from a file doesn't work.

**Below are the steps I have taken which include a deep dive into documentation and trying many answers to similar questions (linked), all to no avail.**

1. I googled the error and found in the docs that loading local data is
   a security risk so it has to be enabled. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54623877/3696204)
   and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile), which was to use the following when logging
   into MySQL:

```
# neither of these worked:
mysql -u [username] -p --local-infile
mysql -u [username] -p --local-infile=1
mysql --local-infile -u [username] -p
```

Maybe when I log in with this option, I'm just setting it on the client side and not the server? I really don't know the difference.

2. Next, I dug into the documentation a little more and read about the
   "local_infile" variable. There is even a section in the documents
   titled **Enabling or Disabling Local Data Loading Capability**,
   where it talks about a system variable called `local_infile` but
   doesn't say a damned thing about how to enable or disable it.
3. So I next read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile) about server system variables
   and how to look at what I've got going on using:

```
mysqld --verbose --help
```

Which printed out a massive amount of text, but I found a line that said:

`Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
C:\Windows\my.ini C:\Windows\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.cnf`

I figured I could find my `local_infile` variable in one of those `.ini` or `.cnf` files and change it to 1 or True or whatever... However, exactly none of those files exist in any of those locations.

4. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10762399/3696204), or more specifically the comments on the
   answer, I found this file: `mysql.conf.sample` which has a few
   variables listed in it but not `local_infile`, nor the host of
   others that were listed in the print out from `mysqld --verbose
   --help`. To this file I added the lines

```
[mysqld]
local_infile=1
```

No luck there.

5. `SET GLOBAL local_infile='ON'` and then `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE`local_infile` results in:

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
```

It was `OFF` before. But guess what, I still can't load two rows into a database from a text file. Shocker.

6. I found a [blog post](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/sqlquerychat/sql-help/others/location-of-mysql-configuration-file-my-cnf-or-my-ini-on-windows-querychat/) that said that config files could be located in the directory `%PROGRAMDATA%/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0` as a `my.ini`. Sure enough, that's where it was. I added `local-infile=1` under `[mysql]` and `[mysqld]`. It still didn't work, so I tried `local-infile` and `local-infile=ON` (I have seen all of these used in various accepted answers). None of them worked.

So, as is the norm, documentation absolutely sucks, and I'm lost. But at least I've done my due diligence of searching the docs, so the pedantics of SO are satisfied and I can ask my question:

**How do I enable loading local data by default?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: Enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile)

Comment: @nbk No it does not. If you had read the question, you would see that I already tried that.

Comment: Load data when enable it, only loads data from a specified folder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql  when you enter there a folder c:\temp it accepts file from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is on windows.
I had same problem. Cannot find a way to turn that local_infile option on. Solution is to use batch files to start mysqld. I use standalone apache/mysql system which starts from where ever directory you extract the zip.

Keys are:

1. To have non blocking batch to start mysqld. 
   First set environment varibles how ever you want but especially note that in that batch you better add mysql bin directory to %path% environment variable.

call ".\..\..\set_roots.bat"

Then start mysqld as parallel process. Again use "call" command:

call start "MYSQL" mysqld --defaults-file=%my_ini% --port=%mysql_port%  --standalone --console --log-timestamps=SYSTEM --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp  --verbose

2. Use timer to wait so that mysqld is ready to take queries

   timeout /t 5
3. Now that mysqld has started we can execute mysql commands at the end of original batch.

Example:

mysql -u root -p%rootpw% -e "SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';"

Note: Leave no space between -p and actual password and it does not ask input